# How to show the previous page data as it is on button click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 webforms default.aspx and default1.aspx.

In default.aspx I have a button on button click event it redirects to default1.aspx?sno=1

then on default1.aspx I have a button back. On back button click the user is redirected to previous page default.aspx.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Write following code in default1.aspx page

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to previous page using Javascript or server.Transfer or PostBackUrl property of button control. You can use any one property that will help for you.